# NestJS circular services not working with Controller

Tags: node.js, typescript, controller, nestjs, circular-dependency

I have a circular dependency like so

Auth.service.ts

```
export class AuthService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => UserService))
    private userService: UserService,
  )
```

User.service.ts

```
export class UserService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => AuthService))
    private authService: AuthService,
  )
```

I have 3 controllers where I access these.

User.controller.ts

```
export class UserController {
  constructor(private readonly userService: UserService) {})
```

Auth.controller.ts

```
export class AuthController {
  constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService) {})
```

AuthUser.controller.ts

```
export class AuthUserController {
  constructor(
    private readonly authService: AuthService,
    private readonly userService: UserService,
  ) {}
```

I have a module.ts file where I'm setting everything up

```
@Module({
  imports: [],
  controllers: [
    AuthUserController,
    AuthController,
    UserController,
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthService,
    UserService,
  ],
```

I have a few endpoints in my controllers. They work fine from AuthController & UserController. But when calling from AuthUserController the classes are not being instantiated in the code. I'm not sure why or what I'm missing

Comment: Are you missing the `@Injectable` decorator on your services or did you just omit them from the excerpt?

Comment: @iced Just omitted from the excerpt.